# How does this code work and is it good practice?

Tags: c

I came across a Fibonacci program on the web and have a question about one of the lines of code.

The program uses unsigned long long ints.

```
fibn = fib0 + fib1;

if((fibn < 0) || (fibn ULLONG_MAX)){
puts("\nOverflow\n");
```

Of course the fibn < 0 makes no sense with regard to unsigned long long ints but my question is about (fibn ULLONG_MAX). There's no comparison operator -- what is it testing?

My compiler, gcc, flags it as "fibn is not a function or pointer." The original program states it was compiled on MS Visual C++ 08.

How does this line of code work and is it good programming practice?

Comment: Did you maybe retype that code instead of copying and pasting it? You should probably provide the entire function.

Comment: I'd recommend not using code from that source

Comment: As shown, this is not valid code.

Comment: It's not going to compile in visual C++ 08 either. Probably the > got lost in in an encoding accident on whatever webpage you found the code on, (ofcourse testing for > ULLONG_MAX is just as much nonsense as testing < 0)

Comment: [is this where you got it from?](http://bytes.com/topic/c/answers/768724-unsigned-long-long-overflow)

Comment: @Ryan Haining yes that is the website

Comment: Did you compile that program before posting here? The program is wrong. It would not even compile.

Comment: the code at the linked web page does not even come close to compiling!!  Trying to compile the code causes the compiler to raise a number of warnings and errors.

Comment: @haccks that's what the question is about

Comment: That code looks like it was munged on upload (same way SO munges code that isn't surrounded by `code` tags.

Comment: @JohnBode: I don't think `fibn < 0` was added or changed by the upload. That just looks like crap.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply put, the code in invalid. `fibn < 0` will never be true because `fibn` is unsigned and any reasonably competant compiler will warn you about that.

`fibn ULLONG_MAX` isn't valid because there is no comparator between them.  The only thing that has any semblance of reason would be `fibn == ULLONG_MAX`, which is a nearly useless comparison because if `fibn` exceeds `ULLONG_MAX` it will wrap around.

What you'd actually do is check to see if `fibn` is less than `fib1` to determine if a wrap-around occured.

Comment: The person who posted the program said his compiler did not complain but Lint did complain. Anyway, the correct test for wraparound (I guess unsigned ints don't technically overflow) is if ( max - fib1 < fib 0) then error.

Comment: @djt the program seems to be written by someone very, very new to programming, I really wouldn't think too much about it if I were you.  [codeproject](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/21194/Iterative-vs-Recursive-Approaches) has a reasonable iterative approach for fib

Comment: @djt: Just take that code for one thing: as a ver, very bad example. Or as very good example how **not** to do it. Read the comments here and delete that code. There's certainly better fib() functions around.

Answer (score 0):

*How does this line of code work and is it good programming practice?*

It does not work, the `>` was most likely lost in translation.

As you noticed, comparing an `unsigned long long` as `< 0` and `> ULLONG_MAX` is useless. If configured with the correct warning level, the compiler will flag these comparisons as having a constant result.

The program is just an attempt posted by an inexperienced programmer on a site that does not even show code properly. Stay around, you will learn much more from stackoverflow.

Comment: "comparing an unsigned long long to 0 ... is useless". Not really. Just comparing `< 0` is (similar for ULLONG_MAX) ;-)